# Questions not displaying on Drupal quiz report form tpl

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am working on Drupal 7 quiz module 7.x-5.0-alpha9 and have created a quiz-report-form.tpl file to display quiz results, however question titles are not rendered in the custom quiz-report-form.tpl. All other data is displayed properly. Can anyone please help with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It works by configuring the /admin/quiz/settings/config.
if not, you can update the module